# Assert difference of number of children in relationship in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assertions, functional-testing

My controller is able to create a child book_loan. I am trying to test this behavior in a functional test but am having a hard time using the assert_difference method. I've tried a number of ways of passing the count of book_loans to assert_difference with no luck.

```
  test "should create loan" do
    @request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] = 'http://test.com/sessions/new'
    assert_difference(books(:ruby_book).book_loans.count, 1) do
      post :loan, {:id => books(:ruby_book).to_param,
                               :book_loan => {:person_id => 1,
                                              :book_id =>
                                                books(:dreaming_book).id}}

    end
  end
```

**can't convert BookLoan into String**

```
assert_difference(books(:ruby_book).book_loans,:count, 1)
```

**NoMethodError: undefined method 'book_loans' for #**

```
assert_difference('Book.book_loans.count', +1)
```

**can't convert Proc into String**

```
assert_difference( lambda{books(:ruby_book).book_loans.count}, :call, 1 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like assert_difference expects a string, which it will eval before and after the block.  So the following may work for you:

```
assert_difference('books(:ruby_book).book_loans.count', 1) do
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble with this too and just figured out how this works.  Like the original post, I too was trying something like this:

```
# NOTE: this is WRONG, see below for the right way.
assert_difference(account.users.count, +1) do                                                                                                       
  invite.accept(another_user)
end
```

This doesn't work because there is no way for `assert_difference` to *perform an action* before it runs the block and after it runs the block.

The reason the string works is that the string can be *evaluated* to determine if the expected difference resulted.

But a string is a string, *not code*.  I believe a better approach is to pass something that can be *called*.  Wrapping the expression in a `lambda` does just that; it allows `assert_difference` to call the lambda to verify the difference:

```
assert_difference(lambda { account.users.count }, +1) do                                                                                                       
  invite.accept(another_user)
end
```